# what would happen if runtime does not throw("concurrent map writes") but panic("concurrent map writes")

Tags: go

[How to recover from concurrent map writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288741/how-to-recover-from-concurrent-map-writes/39289246#39289246?newreg=02bd7b743b044ed0bbecdd49b84dc89a)

as icza said:

> If you would leave your app like that and it wouldn't crash, you could
> experience mysterious, undefined behavior at runtime.

If one goroutine fails to write to a map in case of "concurrent map writes", how about just `panic("concurrent map writes")` instead of `throw("concurrent map writes")`.

Comment: What is this "throw" you speak of?

Comment: What difference would it make? It's still a data race and hence undefined behavior. Use proper synchronization to avoid the concurrent map writes, and so you don't have to worry about either panic nor app crash.

Comment: the only thing that makes `map` different here is that `map` is a more complex builtin data structure - it holds its own logic and invariance between data in it; a data racing write would cause undefined behaviour and possibly data corruption, which might put the map into invalid state (broken invariance) causing following reading and writing to the map undefined behaviour too. while a `panic` instead of a `throw` would make it recoverable, it makes little sense: data race is not something that should or can be fixed at runtime.

Comment: @jub0bs: `throw` is used in the runtime to produce a "fatal error". It's not part of the language spec.

Comment: @JimB Thanks. I learned something. For future readers: https://golang.org/src/runtime/panic.go#L1107

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The runtime cannot detect races, but it can detect when the internal state of a `map` has been corrupted by a data race, and that is what `throw("concurrent map writes")` and `throw("concurrent map read and map write")` are for (`throw` is used extensively in the runtime, to abort the program when there is no safe way to proceed). **Using a `panic` here would imply that you can recover from this situation, but there is no way to recover**, because it is already known that the program state has been corrupted.